# (Marginal) least-squares estimate of an individual marker effect

Tags: mathematical-statistics, marginal-effect

I am reading the paper from Vilhjálmsson et al (2015), [Modeling Linkage Disequilibrium Increases Accuracy of Polygenic Risk Scores](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4596916/), at the "Phenotype Model" section, they said:

> Let Y be a N × 1 phenotype vector and X be a N × M genotype matrix, where N is the number of individuals, and M is the number of genetic variants. For simplicity, we will assume throughout that the phenotype Y and individual genetic variants Xi have been mean centered and standardized to have variance 1. We model the phenotype as a linear combination of M genetic effects and an independent environmental effect ε, i.e., $Y=\sum_{i=1}^{M}X_{i}\beta_{i}+\epsilon$, where $X_{i}$ denotes the ith genetic variant, $\beta_{i}$ is its true effect, and ε is the environmental and noise contribution. In this setting, the (marginal) least-squares estimate of an individual marker effect is $\hat{\beta_{i}} = {X_{i}^{'}}\mathbf {Y}/N$.

I don't know how they got the final expression of the mariginal least-squares estimate of each individual marker effect? From the [OLS Wikipedia] (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_least_squares),
$${\hat {\boldsymbol {\beta }}}=\left(\mathbf {X} ^{\mathsf {T}}\mathbf {X} \right)^{-1}\mathbf {X} ^{\mathsf {T}}\mathbf {y} $$

But, how does this link to the expression in this paper?

I really need some help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It can be seen from the article “Asymptotic Properties of Marginal Least-Square Estimator for Ultrahigh-Dimensional Linear Regression Models with Correlated Errors”,X^{T}X/n=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The prime notation $'$ actually means $^T$ (transpose) here. And if you look lower down on the wikipedia page:

> The product $N=X^T X$ is a Gram matrix

So they're different ways of writing the same function.

Also, just a note that [PRS-CS](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41467-019-09718-5) is much more commonly used than LDPred these days.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I got it, so $N$ is the product in this equation, it is not the nunber of individuals mentioned at the beginning of the paragraph. The PRS-CS is a good recommendation. Thanks again.

Comment: @DavidB PRS-CS is more used than LDPred v1 but not LDPred2. It is good though

Comment: @BigMistake I'd be curious to know what field you're coming from? PRS-CS has 792 google scholar citations (305 in 2023), LDPred2 has 292 (138 in 2023). But I agree, there are several methods now that achieve very comparable results.

Comment: @DavidB I stand corrected! That's very cool.